# Communicating Rserve and C#

Tags: c#, r, rserve

Most of the questions that somewhat relate to this link to old/deprecated resources, so I'm asking it once more.

I have a special tool that gets a lot of traffic and utilizes complex computations through R. We have opted to use Rserve to be able to intake a large influx of concurrent requests, but we cannot figure out how to communicate our C# ASP.NET web application with RServe. **We have RServe up and running, but how can we actually communicate and make requests straight to Rserve from a C# application? The documentation for https://github.com/konne/RserveCLI2 isn't great, can someone help us understand how to call our functions?**

Note: We have a plumber implementation up and running. It works great, but it seems to have issues with large amounts of concurrent requests as it simply queues them. The documentation talks about off-loading and creating parallel processes, but this may require a lot of parallel processes if each can only handle 1 request.